# Trying to store multiple values into a variable using loop and insertion also using that particular variable

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I want to write pl/sql to store **multiple values** into a variable and behalf of that variable I want to insert the values which are returned in variable. But it does not work - what can I do? Please help me out. My first select statement always returns 12-13 rows which I want to store into `vtm` variable.

```
DECLARE
   vtm  NUMBER (38);

   -- vtm student.gr_number%TYPE;
   tab  apex_application_global.vc_arr2;
BEGIN
   tab := APEX_UTIL.string_to_table (vtm);

   SELECT s.gr_number
     INTO vtm
     FROM student s
          LEFT JOIN class_time ct
             ON     ct.class_id = s.class_id
                AND INSTR (s.class_time, ct.class_time) > 0
    WHERE     UPPER (TRIM (ct.class_id)) = UPPER (TRIM ( :APP_USER))
          AND s.gr_number IS NOT NULL
          AND is_active_flg = 'Y';

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (vtm);

   FOR i IN vtm .. tab.COUNT
   LOOP
      BEGIN
         INSERT INTO student_class_attend (gr_number,
                                           student_id,
                                           period_next_day_flg,
                                           attend_date,
                                           period_start_dt,
                                           period_end_dt,
                                           period_duration,
                                           course_name,
                                           class_time,
                                           branch_id,
                                           shift_id,
                                           teacher_id,
                                           class_id,
                                           marked_by,
                                           course_id,
                                           class_uid)
              VALUES ( :P7_GR_NUMBER,
                      :P7_STUDENT_ID,
                      :P7_PERIOD_NEXT_DAY_FLG,
                      TO_DATE (UPPER ( :P7_ATTEND_DATE), 'DD-MON-YYYY'),
                      :P7_PERIOD_START_DT,
                      :P7_PERIOD_END_DT,
                      :P7_PERIOD_DURATION,
                      :P7_COURSE_NAME,
                      :P7_CLASS_TIME,
                      :P7_BRANCH_ID,
                      :P7_SHIFT_ID,
                      :P7_TEACHER_ID,
                      :P7_CLASS_ID,
                      :v_employee_id,
                      :P7_COURSE_ID,
                      :P7_CLASS_UID);
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
         THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('there is no data..');
      END;
   END LOOP;

   COMMIT;
END;
```

see gr images list which i want to store into vtm and insert all the record on one click button [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfVfq.png)

Answer (score 2):

To cut a long story short, you're doing it in a wrong manner, overcomplicating things. Everything can be done in a single SQL statement; no need for arrays, loops ... nothing.

```
INSERT INTO STUDENT_CLASS_ATTEND (gr_number,
                                  student_id,
                                  PERIOD_NEXT_DAY_FLG,
                                  attend_date,
                                  period_start_dt,
                                  period_end_dt,
                                  PERIOD_DURATION,
                                  course_name,
                                  class_time,
                                  branch_id,
                                  shift_id,
                                  teacher_id,
                                  class_id,
                                  marked_by,
                                  course_id,
                                  class_uid)
   SELECT :P7_GR_NUMBER,
          :P7_STUDENT_ID,
          :P7_PERIOD_NEXT_DAY_FLG,
          TO_DATE (UPPER ( :P7_ATTEND_DATE), 'DD-MON-YYYY'),
          :P7_PERIOD_START_DT,
          :P7_PERIOD_END_DT,
          :P7_PERIOD_DURATION,
          :P7_COURSE_NAME,
          :P7_CLASS_TIME,
          :P7_BRANCH_ID,
          :P7_SHIFT_ID,
          :P7_TEACHER_ID,
          :P7_CLASS_ID,
          s.gr_number,       --> this is what you wanted to put into VTM
          :P7_COURSE_ID,
          :P7_CLASS_UID
     FROM student s
          LEFT JOIN class_time ct
             ON     ct.class_id = s.class_id
                AND INSTR (s.class_time, ct.class_time) > 0
    WHERE     UPPER (TRIM (ct.class_id)) = UPPER (TRIM ( :APP_USER))
          AND s.gr_number IS NOT NULL
          AND is_active_flg = 'Y';
```

Comment: i have multiple values which is returned from this query almost 12-13 rows it return which i want to store in vtm and insert all the returned  values which is getting from such query for a single value it is fine but for 12-13 values i need loop              SELECT s.gr_number
     INTO vtm
     FROM student s
          LEFT JOIN class_time ct
             ON     ct.class_id = s.class_id
                AND INSTR (s.class_time, ct.class_time) > 0
    WHERE     UPPER (TRIM (ct.class_id)) = UPPER (TRIM ( :APP_USER))
          AND s.gr_number IS NOT NULL
          AND is_active_flg = 'Y';

Comment: bro check about image hope you will understant what is my objective click on above image description to see the fetched result which is required to insert on single click button process